# Flippin image in css continously

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to flip a object continously i have the following code but this will flip the image only on hover and only once. I want the image to start flipping as soon as the page loads and continue flipping till the page is shut. Please help.

CSS : in indicates the container and front and back indicates the front and back side of image

```
.in{

    /* How pronounced should the 3D effects be */
    perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    position:relative;
}

.front,
.back{

    /* Enable 3D transforms */
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    /* We are using two separate divs for the front and back of the
       phone. This will hide the divs when they are flipped, so that the
       opposite side can be seen:  */

    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position:absolute;



    /* Animate the transitions */
    transition:5.8s;
}

.back{

    /* The back side is flipped 180 deg by default */
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);

    background-position:right center;
}

.in:hover .front{
    /* When the container is hovered, flip the front side and hide it .. */
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.in:hover .back{
    /* .. at the same time flip the back side into visibility */
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Comment: with **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, it can look like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/rvrvqdsp/)**.

Answer (score 0):

use css `animation`:

```css
.flip{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:30px;
  background:green;  
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-animation:rotate linear 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation:rotate linear 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:rotate linear 2s infinite;
  animation:rotate linear 2s infinite;
}

@-o-keyframes rotate{ from { -o-transform: rotateY(0deg) } to { -o-transform: rotateY(360deg) } }
@-moz-keyframes rotate{ from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) } to { -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg) } }
@-webkit-keyframes rotate{ from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) } to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) } }
@keyframes rotate{ from { transform: rotateY(0deg) } to { transform: rotateY(360deg) } }
```

```html
<div class="flip"></div>
```